# Pandas выдает ошибку AttributeError

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

хочу вносить данные в sql server через этот код:

```
for row in df_write_dbase.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO dbo._Reference2565 (_Description,_Fld2651,_Fld2652,_Fld2655,_Fld2656,_Fld2657,_Fld2659,_Fld3639,_Fld3640)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''',
                row._Description,
                row._Fld2651,
                row._Fld2652,
                row._Fld2655,
                row._Fld2656,
                row._Fld2657,
                row._Fld2659,
                row._Fld3639,
                row._Fld3640,
                )
conn_write2dbase.commit()
```

но выдает такую ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute '_Description'
```

скажите, пожалуйста, что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: пример датафрейма приведите в вопросе.

Comment: Покажите что напечатает `print(df_write_dbase.columns)`. Судя по всему у вас нет такой колонки в датафрейме.

Comment: Index(['_IDRRef', '_Version', '_Marked', '_PredefinedID', '_ParentIDRRef',
       '_Folder', '_Code', '_Description', '_Fld2651', '_Fld2652', '_Fld2653',
       '_Fld2654', '_Fld2655', '_Fld2656', '_Fld2657', '_Fld2658', '_Fld2659',
       '_Fld2660', '_Fld3639', '_Fld3640'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NiYsTmDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, используйте `iterrows`:

```py
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    ...
```

`itertuples` поля с подчёркиванием превращает в `_1`, `_2` и т.д. по какой-то причине.

Comment: теперь такая ошибка: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Неверный входящий поток табличных данных (TDS) по протоколу удаленного вызова процедур (RPC). Параметр 5 (""): переданное значение не является допустимым экземпляром типа данных float. Проверьте исходные данные на наличие неверных значений. Пример недопустимого значения: числовые данные, масштаб которых больше, чем точность. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Может у вас NA в данных? Или пустая строка. Это надо данные смотреть

Comment: да, есть пустые ячейки.

Comment: А в базе поля nullable?

Comment: да, теперь такая ошибка:  SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an exception set